# Performing calculations on a numpy array and adding them to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have an array such as this:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]])
```

and a dataframe such as this:

```
  num letter
0   1      a
1   2      b
2   3      c
```

What I would then like to do is to calculate the difference between the first and last number in each sequence in the array and ultimately add this difference to a new column in the df.

Currently I am able to calculate the desired difference in each sequence in this manner:

```
for i in a:
    print(i[-1] - i[0])
```

Giving me the following results:

```
6
30
12
```

I would expect to be able to do is replace the `print` with `df['new_col']` like so:

```
df['new_col'] = (i[-1] - i[0])
```

And for my df to then look like this:

```
  num letter new_col
0   1      a      6
1   2      b      30
2   3      c      12
```

However, I end up getting this:

```
  num letter  new_col
0   1      a       12
1   2      b       12
2   3      c       12
```

I would also really appreciate if anyone could tell me what the equivalent of `.diff()` and `.shift()` are in numpy as I tried that in the same way you would with a pandas dataframe as well but just got error messages. This would be useful for me if I want to calculate the difference not just between the first and last numbers but somewhere in between.

Any help would be really appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry about this, in my haste to ask the question I asked it with a slight inaccuracy which is causing me an issue. My df is actually longer, than the array. Lets say my df is actually 4 rows long
`  num letter
0   1      a
1   2      b
2   3      c
3   4      d`
When trying to perform the code in your answer I get the error message ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
It works perfectly when my df and array are the same number of rows but not otherwise. I just want nans to appear where the array has no number to give. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently you are only performing the difference calculation in the very last one

use a list comprehension:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]])

b = [i[-1] - i[0] for i in a]
```

if the lengths mismatch, then you need to extend the list with NaNs:

```
b = b + [np.NaN]*(len(df) - len(b))
df['new_col'] = b
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate

Comment: Hi mate, sorry to be a pain, but I actually asked something slightly wrong in my question, I added a comment under my original question explaining, I just wondered if you knew how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Might be better off doing this in a DataFrame if your array grows in size.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a.T)

df['new_col'] = df1.iloc[-1] - df1.iloc[0]

print(df)

   num letter  new_col
0    1      a        6
1    2      b       30
2    3      c       12
```